# Keep NSTextView's Font From Changing

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, fonts, nstextview

I thought this would be straight forward, but it looks like I was wrong. Basically, all I'm trying to do is keep the font from changing to the Apple default: Helvetica Regular 12pt.

I've made a subclass of NSDocument and in my implementation file I have the following method:

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController*)aController
{
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];

    if(attrString)
    {
        [[textView textStorage] setAttributedString:attrString];
        [[textView textStorage] setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Menlo Bold" size:24]];
    }
```

This method works all right when I open a file, but if I delete all of the text and then type again, the font resets to... Helvetica Regular 12pt... All I want is to keep the font and size as I specified it for the entire life of the program.

Comment: Why don't you set the font in the attributed string rather than the text view?

Comment: Because I'm a rookie and don't know what I'm doing. After a few more chapters of this book, I realize that does look kind of funny.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the typing attributes of the text view to contain your font for the key NSFontAttributeName.

However, I would go a step further.  If you know you NEVER want a certain font in your model (NSTextStorage -- the backing store for NSTextView), simply subclass NSTextStorage and override the attribute setters and getters.  NSTextView gives the user access to font menus and copy/paste will still allow certain fonts in.  The only way to truly guarantee it never enters your text view is to never allow it into the model.